# rake db:seed error in rails 4.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a rails app that won't load data to database on `rake db:seed`.

I tried to find out by `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=developement --trace` it gives following **error**

> ** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
>
> ** Execute db:seed
>
> ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
>
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute environment
>
> rake aborted!
>
> database configuration does not specify adapter
>
> /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in
>   `resolve_hash_connection'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in`
>   resolve_string_connection'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in
>   `spec'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in`
>   establish_connection'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:170:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`
>   instance_eval'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in
>   `execute_hook'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in`
>   block in on_load'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in`
>   on_load'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:168:in
>   `block in <class:Railtie>'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
>   instance_exec'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`
>   block in run_initializers'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in
>   `block in tsort_each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in`
>   block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in
>   `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in`
>   block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in`
>   each_strongly_connected_component'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in
>   `tsort_each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
>   run_initializers'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in
>   `initialize!'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/MacBook/rails_projects/medicaldevicehub/config/environment.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in
>   `block in require'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in`
>   load_dependency'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:188:in`
>   require_environment!'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:248:in
>   `block in run_tasks_blocks'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `block in invoke_prerequisites'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in
>   `invoke_prerequisites'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in
>   `call'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`
>   block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`
>   block in top_level'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in
>   `run_with_threads'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in`
>   top_level'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in
>   `block in run'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in`
>   '
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake:23:in`
>   '
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in
>   `eval'
>   /Users/MacBook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`
>   ' Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment

Here is my **database.yml** file:

```
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

production:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/production.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Comment: error message says you have pending migrations: "Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations"

Comment: After migration I still have this problem.

Comment: try `rake db:seed development`

Comment: it would be useful if you could also share your seed file.

Comment: @Tim I already figured out the issue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo

rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=**developement** --trace

Make it

rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=development --trace